# String split to table on whole column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace, split

I have two tables, the first, dbo.QuestionaireResponse includes the columns PersonID (int not null), ApplicationID (int not null) and RaceIDs.  PersonID is a basic ID column, but RaceIDs is a varchar(255) that contains comma delimited strings of ID's (bad design I know). The other table is a type table dbo.Race with two columns, RaceID (int identity) and RaceDescription (varchar of some sort).  I need to output a table in one of the two following formats:

1. PersonID, RaceDescription as a one to many relationship
2. PersonID, RaceDescriptions (a comma delimited string of values from the race description collumn)

In my research I came across this post http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/ but it doesn't quite fit the problem because the split has to be preformed on every record in the column.

I ended up passing the type table to the webservice in addition to the data, but I'm curious if there's another viable solution.  Performance matters in this case though the type table does have a small number or records.

Any suggestions for how to do this in sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT q.PersonID, r.RaceDescription
FROM dbo.QuestionaireResponse q JOIN dbo.Race r 
ON ',' + q.RaceIDs + ','  LIKE  '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(10),r.RaceID) + ',%';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39fe0/2)